# How to hide label when there is no data?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one label in html to which I am binding value coming from JSON.

I need to show a label when there is some value, otherwise I want to hide that label.

Can any one suggest the way to do it?

Thanks.

[image]

```
<li>
  <strong>
    Bad Address Date:
  </strong> 
  {{insuredProfile.permanentAddress.badAddressDate}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-if`

```
<li ng-if="insuredProfile.permanentAddress.badAddressDate.length">
   <strong>Bad Address Date:</strong> 
   {{insuredProfile.permanentAddress.badAddressDate}}  
</li>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/2CHKf/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-show`:

```
<li ng-show="insuredProfile.permanentAddress.badAddressDate"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-show or ng-hide. A working plunker [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nv48cwvNBnSFaBGthTik?p=preview)

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <li ng-show="dateShown"><strong>Bad Address Date:</strong> {{dateShown}}  </li>
   <li ng-show="dateNotShown"><strong>Bad Address Date:</strong> {{dateNotShown}}  </li>
  </body>
```